# How game engine rotates models?

Tags: rotation, game-engine

if i do a human model and import him to game engine. does game engine knows all point cordinates on model and rotates each ones? all models consists million points and and if i rotate a model 90 degree , does game engine calculates millions point new location and rotate? how does it works. Thanks

Comment: Models do not consist of "millions of points": it's that simple.  A model may have 100s or 1000s of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a vague question since each game engine will work differently, but in general the game engine **will not** touch the model coordinates.

Models are usually loaded with **model space** (or local space) coordinates - this simply means that each vertex is defined with a location relative to the **origin** of that model. The origin is defined as (0,0,0) and is the point around which rotations take place.

Now the game engine loads and keeps the model in this coordinate space. Then you provide your transformations (such as translation and rotation matrices) to place that model somewhere in your "world" (i.e. the global coordinate space shared by all objects). You also provide the way you want to view this world with various other transforms such projection and view matrices.

The game engine then takes all of these transformations and passes them to the GPU (or software renderer, in some cases) - it will also setup other stuff such as textures, etc. These are usually set once per frame (or per object for a frame).

Finally, it then passes **each** vertex that needs to be processed to the renderer. Each vertex is then **transformed** by the renderer using all the transformations specified to get a final vertex position - first in world space and then in screen space - which it can use to render pixels based on various other information (such as textures and lighting).

So the point is, in most cases, the engine really has nothing to do with the rotation of the model/vertices. It is simply a way to manage the model and the various settings that apply to it.

Of course, the engine **can** rotate the model and modify it's vertices, but this is usually only done during loading - for example if the model needs to be converted between different coordinate spaces.

There is a lot more going on, and this is a very basic description of what actually happens. There are many many sources that describe this process in great detail, so I won't even try to duplicate it. Hopefully this gives you enough detail to understand the basics.